# write to serial port with win32 API- port won't open until i open it else where

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port

I tried to write to a serial port in C++ with WIN32 API , the WriteFile doesn't return ERROR_IO_PENDING but nothing happens, But after i write to the port using another program (in C#) the c++ program works until i restart windows 7 , here is the write code:

```
static DCB dcb = {0};
static HANDLE hComm;
static int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    hComm = CreateFile(
    L"\\\\.\\COM3",
    GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    NULL,   
    NULL
    );

if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) // error opening port; abort
    printf_s("INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE\n");

if (GetCommState(hComm, &dcb))// DCB is ready for use.
{
    dcb.BaudRate = CBR_19200; //19200 Baud
    dcb.ByteSize = 8; //8 data bits
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY; //no parity
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT; //1 stop
    printf_s("set UP DCB\n");
}
else // Error getting current DCB settings
    printf_s("ERROR getting \n"+GetLastError());

osWrite.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    WriteABuffer("!serialCMDtoSend\r",sizeof("!serialCMDtoSend\r");
}
static BOOL WriteABuffer(char * lpBuf, DWORD dwToWrite)
{
        // Issue write.
        if (!WriteFile(hComm, lpBuf, dwToWrite, &dwWritten, &osWrite)) 
        {
            if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) { // WriteFile failed, but it isn't delayed. Report error and abort.
                fRes = FALSE;
            }
            else {
                // Write is pending.
                if (!GetOverlappedResult(hComm, &osWrite, &dwWritten, TRUE))
                    fRes = FALSE;
                else
                    fRes = TRUE;// Write operation completed successfully.
            }
        }
        else
            fRes = TRUE;        // WriteFile completed immediately.
    return fRes;
}
```

can anybody see my bug ?

Answer (score 2):

This works by accident.  You forgot to specify FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED in the CreateFile call so you can never get overlapped I/O.  You probably didn't know about this because your error handling is broken, you have no idea what the error code looks like when GetLastError doesn't return ERROR_IO_PENDING.  It works by accident when WriteFile doesn't have to block because the data fits in the driver's transmit buffer.  Modulo the handshaking setup as Ben explained.

There's no point at all in using overlapped I/O and calling GetOverlappedResult(TRUE) immediately.  You might as well use non-overlapped I/O, a lot easier to get going.  Only use it if you have something else useful to do and can call WaitForMultipleObjects() to check if the write completed.  That's usually hard to deal with in the case of writing, writing asynchronous code isn't easy.

Comment: Then don't.  Pass NULL instead of &osWrite.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes starting with a clean DCB is better than using `GetCommState`.  For example, you aren't turning off flow control, so behavior depends on how the last program left it.

You definitely need to be setting the flow control fields correctly:

```
fOutxCtsFlow
fOutxDsrFlow
fDtrControl
fDsrSensitivity
fOutX
fInX
fRtsControl
```

In general, I suggest NOT using `GetCommState` if you don't want your program to depend on prior settings.  Instead, start with everything zero:

```
DCB dcb = { sizeof dcb };
dcb.fBinary = TRUE;
dcb.BaudRate = 19200; //19200 Baud
dcb.ByteSize = 8; //8 data bits
dcb.Parity = NOPARITY; //no parity
dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT; //1 stop
```

In addition to your dependence on prior settings, `GetCommState` is failing because you didn't set `DCBlength` (the documentation clearly says this must be set by you, the caller.  `GetCommState` can't fill in the buffer without first checking the size you supply.).

Comment: The example that i was trying to faloow is from msdn:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx
there they reset DCB like this:
     DCB dcb = {0};

Comment: @user1120007: I've reported the documentation bug.  The `DCBlength` member needs to be set before calling `GetCommState`.  This is pretty common for Win32 APIs that accept a structure, since the structure size can change between Windows versions, you need to tell Windows which size (version) of the structure your program uses.  (Otherwise there would be no reason to have the size in the structure at all)